# how to map two ports with C program in linux

Tags: c

I want to map two ports (anything goes to port x goes to port y and visa versa )with a C program, I wrote this program but it does not work.
This is my code:

```
int recv_all_nonblock(int sockfd,char* buff,int buffersize)
{
    int numbytes;
    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buff, buffersize-1, MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_DONTWAIT)) <= 0)
    {
    perror("recv");
    }
    else if( numbytes>0)
    {
    buff[numbytes] = '\0';
    }

    return numbytes;
}


int sendall(int sockfd, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
    int bytesleft = *len; // how many we have left to send
    int n=0;
    while(total < *len)
    {
    n = send(sockfd, buf+total, bytesleft, MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if (n == -1) { break; }
    total += n;
    bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total; // return number actually sent here

    return n==-1?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}


int Connect_To_Remote(char *Addr,char* PORT)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo=NULL, *p=NULL;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];



    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    while (p==NULL)
    {
    sleep(5);
    while((rv = getaddrinfo(Addr, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        sleep(5);
    }

    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
        {
        perror("client: socket");
        continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("client: connect");
        continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
    }
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure
    return sockfd;

}
int recv_all(int sockfd,char* buff,int buffersize)
{
    int numbytes;
    fd_set readfd_set;
    struct timeval recvwait;

    recvwait.tv_sec=10;
    recvwait.tv_usec=0;
    FD_ZERO(&readfd_set);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfd_set);
    if(select(sockfd+1, &readfd_set, NULL, NULL, &recvwait) <= 0)
    {
    perror("wait for recieve error:");
    }
    else
    {
    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buff, buffersize-1, MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_DONTWAIT)) == -1)
    {
        perror("recv");
    }
    else if( numbytes>0)
    {
        buff[numbytes] = '\0';
    }

    return numbytes;
    }

    return 0;
}

void *Port_Mapper()
{
    int sockfd,newfd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *tmpaddrinfo;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int rv;
    int yes=1;
    int ret=0;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    while (1)
    {
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, MapPort, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        sleep(2);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    }

    while (1)
    {
    for(tmpaddrinfo = servinfo; tmpaddrinfo != NULL; tmpaddrinfo = tmpaddrinfo->ai_next)
    {
        if ((sockfd = socket(tmpaddrinfo->ai_family,tmpaddrinfo->ai_socktype,tmpaddrinfo->ai_protocol)) == -1)
        {
        perror("server: socket");
        continue;
        }
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,sizeof(int)) == -1)
        {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (bind(sockfd, tmpaddrinfo->ai_addr, tmpaddrinfo->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("server: bind");
        continue;
        }

        break;
    }
    if (tmpaddrinfo == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    }
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure
    if (listen(sockfd, MAXLISTENQ) == -1)
    {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
    }
    int bufpoint=0;
    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");
    while(1)
    {  // main accept() loop
    char buff[MAX_SOCK_BUFFER];
    char buff2[MAX_SOCK_BUFFER];
    ret=0;
    int sockfdweb=0;
    sin_size = sizeof (their_addr);
    printf("mapping server: going to  accept connections...\n");
    newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    printf("\n\nmapping server: connections accepted:%d\n",newfd);

    sockfdweb=Connect_To_Remote("192.168.1.10","80");
    if (sockfdweb<0)
    {
        printf("can not connect to %s\n","192.168.1.10");
        break;
    }
      while(1)
    {



        memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));
        ret=recv_all_nonblock(newfd,buff,MAX_SOCK_BUFFER);
printf("recved from client1,%d\n",ret);
        if (ret<=0)
        {
        perror("recieve error from browser:");
        close(newfd);
        sin_size = sizeof (their_addr);
        printf("mapping server: going to  accept connections...\n");
        newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
          ret=recv_all_nonblock(newfd,buff,MAX_SOCK_BUFFER);
    printf("recved from client10,%d\n",ret);
        if (ret<=0)
        {
            perror("recieve error from browser:");
            close(newfd);
            sin_size = sizeof (their_addr);
            printf("mapping server: going to  accept connections...\n");
            newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        }
        else if(ret>0)
        {
    printf("recved from client0\n");
    printf("%s\n",buff);
            if (sendall(sockfdweb,buff,&bufpoint)<0)
            {
            printf("can not send data to %s\n","192.168.1.10");
            }
    printf("send to 80,0\n");

        }

        }
        else if(ret>0)
        {
printf("recved from client\n");
    printf("%s\n",buff);
        if (sendall(sockfdweb,buff,&bufpoint)<0)
        {
            printf("can not send data to %s\n","192.168.1.10");
        }
    printf("send to 80\n");

        }

        memset(buff2,0,sizeof(buff2));
        ret=recv_all_nonblock(sockfdweb,buff2,MAX_SOCK_BUFFER);
printf("recv from 80...%d\n",ret);
        if (ret<=0)
        {
        close(sockfdweb);
        sockfdweb=Connect_To_Remote("192.168.1.10","80");
        if (sockfdweb<0)
        {
            printf("can not connect to %s\n","192.168.1.10");
            break;
        }
        ret=recv_all_nonblock(sockfdweb,buff2,MAX_SOCK_BUFFER);
    printf("recv from 80.9..%d\n",ret);
        if (ret<=0)
        {
            close(sockfdweb);
            sockfdweb=Connect_To_Remote("192.168.1.10","80");
            if (sockfdweb<0)
            {
            printf("can not connect to %s\n","192.168.1.10");
            break;
            }

        }
        else if (ret>0)
        {
    printf("recved from 809\n");
            if (sendall(newfd,buff2,&ret)<0)
            {
            printf("can not send data to %s\n","192.168.1.10");
            }
    printf("send to client9\n");

        }

        }
        else if (ret>0)
        {
printf("recved from 80\n");
        if (sendall(newfd,buff2,&ret)<0)
        {
            printf("can not send data to %s\n","192.168.1.10");
        }
printf("send to client\n");

        }


    }

    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
.
.
.
.
    pthread_attr_init (&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate (&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_create(&portmapper_threadid,&attr,Port_Mapper,NULL);
    pthread_attr_destroy (&attr);
.
.
.
.
}
```

I putted some "printf" in Port_Mapper function and made some changes to trace what happens when I request a web in my browser like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8090/

and the program out put of refreshing two or three times of browser is this:

> mapping server: connections accepted:5
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recved from client1,360
>   recved from client
>   GET /1/ HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 127.0.0.1:8090
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>
> send to 80
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80...-1
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80.9..-1
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recved from client1,-1
>   recieve error from browser:: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   mapping server: going to accept connections...
>   recved from client10,360
>   recved from client0
>   GET /1/ HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 127.0.0.1:8090
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>
> send to 80,0
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80...0
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80.9..-1
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recved from client1,-1
>   recieve error from browser:: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   mapping server: going to accept connections...
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recved from client10,-1
>   recieve error from browser:: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   mapping server: going to accept connections...
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80...0
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80.9..-1
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recved from client1,332
>   recved from client
>   GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 127.0.0.1:8090
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Connection: keep-alive
>
> send to 80
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80...-1
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80.9..-1
>   client: connecting to 192.168.1.10
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recved from client1,-1
>   recieve error from browser:: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   mapping server: going to accept connections...

as you can see the program receive data from browser correctly but when it sends the data to webserver and wants to receive data from web server it always gets error and does not receive any data from web server:

> send to 80
>   recv: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   recv from 80...-1

I have to say that the web server works correctly with no problem.
Can any body tell me what is my problem????

Comment: Can you shorten down the code you have? It's way to much to skim through. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is much to complicated for such an easy task. It can be simplified quote a lot, see this (pseudo) code:

```
void mapper()
{
    int server_socket = create_server_socket();

    for (;;)
    {
        int incomming_socket = accept(server_socket);

        int web_server_socket = connect_to_webserver();

        make_socket_nonblocking(incomming_socket);
        make_socket_nonblocking(web_server_socket);

        for (;;)
        {
            int disconnected = 0;

            FD_ZERO(&read_set);

            FD_SET(incomming_socket, &read_set);
            FD_SET(web_server_socket, &read_set);

            select(max_socket + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            if (FD_ISSET(incomming_socket, &read_set))
            {
                disonnected = recv_and_send(incomming_socket, web_server_socket);
            }
            if (!disconnected && FD_ISSET(web_server_socket, &read_set))
            {
                disconnected = recv_and_send(web_server_socket, incomming_socket);
            }

            if (disconnected)
                break;
        }

        close(web_server_socket);
        close(incomming_socket);
    }
}

int recv_and_send(from_socket, to_socket)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    for (;;)
    {
        len = recv_all(from_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (len < 0)
            return 1;  /* Disconnect */
        if (len == 0)
            break;  /* No more to read for now */

        if (send_all(to_socket, buffer, len) < 0)
            return 1;  /* Disconnect */
    }

    return 0;
}

int recv_all(socket_fd, char *buffer, const size_t buflen)
{
    size_t total_recv = 0;
    size_t remaining_len = buflen;

    while (remaining_len > 0)
    {
        ssize_t len = recv(socket_fd, buffer + total_recv, remaining_len);
        if (len < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
                break;  /* No more to read at the moment */
            return -1;  /* An error */
        }
        if (len == 0)
            break;  /* Connection closed */

        total_recv += len;
        remaining_len -= len;
    }

    return total_recv;
}
```

[The rest I leave as an exercise.]

The main difference with your code, is that the main loop is *much* simpler. You don't need multiple `accept` calls (why do you need it?) or several different read and write functions. Parts of my code can be even further simplified, like the `recv_all` function.

It should also be noted that my code above only handles one connection at a time. One way to solve this is to create a new thread for each incoming connection, or use a more advance method using lists of connections and buffers, and `select` to multiplex between them and the listening socket.